# How to use ampersand in JDBC?

Tags: oracle, jdbc

In oracle we using `select * from table_name where column_name=&value` in similar way how to use ampersand in `JDBC`?

```
stmt = conn.createStatement();
      String sql;
      sql="select emp_name from employees"+" where emp_no=?";
      ResultSet rs=stmt.executeQuery(sql);
      while(rs.next()){
          String emp_name=rs.getString("emp_name");
        System.out.println(emp_name);  

      }
```

i wrote the above code but it is not working(showing error)

Comment: I guess you want to specify a parameter for your query? Check this article [JDBC Example](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html)

Comment: You can't. As far as I know single-ampersand substitution is not a feature of Oracle (as a database), but from SQL*Plus (as a query tool).

Comment: pass values from user and then show matching values in table to user.This is am thinking(how to write the query in jdbc for this purpose)

Comment: @user2854207 Read the tutorial that Przemyslaw links to, it explains how you pass parameters in JDBC.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you read the article I provided the link to?

You use the question mark `?` to point out places in your query where you want to specify a parameter, and you have to use PreparedStatement. I can't test it, but it should be something like this:

```java
// some code to obtain the Connection object

PreparedStatement stmt = null;
String yourQuery = " SELECT emp_name FROM employees WHERE emp_no = ? ";

try {
  stmt = conn.prepareStatement(yourQuery);
  stmt.setLong(1, 252);

  ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery();

  while(rs.next()) {
    String emp_name = rs.getString("emp_name");
    System.out.println(emp_name);
  } 
} finally {
  // close the stmt etc.
}
```

Comment: You've missed the bit where you set the parameter value... *8-)

Comment: @AlexPoole Hah, I did :) Thanks!

Comment: thanq well explanation

Answer (score 2):

I'd suggest using a `PreparedStatement` - from memory it's something like

```
Connection conn = getConnection();
PreparedStatement pstmnt = conn.prepareStatement("Select * from employees where emp_no =?");
pstmnt.setLong(1,emp_no);
ResultSet rs = pstmnt.executeQuery();
```

but the link that @Przemyslaw Kruglej high light above will almost certainly have a good example ( I haven;t read it though ... )

Comment: in our code something miss(like semi coluns and brace please verify that)

Comment: Looks like you are missing the equivalent of "pstmnt.setLong(1,emp_no)" in my example above. The question mark in the conn.prepareStatement(...) statement is a Bind Variable. You need to set that bind variable to the value that is to be used at runtime.